# How to create custom dynamic layout using xib?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have new one in autolayout and swift. I just want to design such box, In that user can pick images and write for something and post it. But Box option are not fix In type and maximum 4 box option are available for user. 
My basic question is how to develop this kind of design for both iphone and ipad in xib. your suggestion and links are very help full for me.
[image: Design Images]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UICollectionView` for this. The upper part can be Header of the `UICollectionView` and bottom part can be attached to your `UIViewController's` view.

Have a look at this tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1